# Concatenate Spannable String and String

Tags: java, android, string

Is there a built in function or anything similar In android/java that allows you to concatenate a spannable string and a string? Ive been searching but I haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 7):

Both are `CharSequence`.

```
    CharSequence charSequence = new SpannableString("text") + "text";
```

If you want to keep spans you can use a `SpannableStringBuilder` to concatenate them and preserve styling.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I then converted the result to a spannable string.

Comment: The issue is that the spans are not persisted. The are just treated as strings.

Comment: I have edited my answer - you can use `SpannableStringBuilder`

Comment: I didn't understand how to use SpannableStringBuilder but I was able to convert my string to Spannable String, I then used TextUtils.concat(SpannableString1, SpannableString2), I then casted the result to spannable string since the result from concat was char